# Using Workflow Manager in a Farm

Tags: 2013, workflow, project-server

We're going to be deploying SharePoint 2013 with Project Server 2013 added, and reading up on it, it will require a Workflow Manager instance.

Our SharePoint farm will be a 3 box instance, with a WFE, an App server hosting most of the service apps (including Project Server 2013), as well as a third box that will be hosting our BI infrastructure (SQL Server 2012, SSAS, SSIS, and SSRS running integrated).

The plan is to have Workflow Manager co-located on the apps box. My question is if the Workflow Manager client needs to be installed/configured on either of the WFE or the BI box, or because all the service apps will be on the same box as workflow manager, will only minimal config be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st its depend the load on your farm, if you have not too much traffic then its ok to install   the WF manager on App servers.  From your configuration lookalike you have alot of things going on, i would go a dedicated server or server with less load.

Yes, the Workflow Manager Client should be installed on every server in the SharePoint Server 2013 farm. This is to accomodate the fact that it is common to move SharePoint servers between roles and if a server that does not have the Workflow Manager Client installed takes on the role of a Web Front End (WFE) then workflow will break.

Here is the link for [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx)