# How to install/use SharePoint 2013 workflow template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have to use the SP 2013 workflow, but somehow that option is not available in the drop down menu "Choose the workflow platform for the new workflow"
[image]

I have installed **workflowmanager.exe** and also fired the command:

```
-Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite “your Web URL>”
-WorkflowHostUri “The same url which you opened in IE to get the certificate. This will be in HTTPS mode>” -AllowOAuthHttp
```

Comment: please see the questions already posted here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164166/install-workflow-manager-on-which-servers and here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86551/using-workflow-manager-in-a-farm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow service application proxy should be connected to web application

You can follow this link for better understanding

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2c260d6a-34e8-43b5-805c-1f1f00c88563/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-platform-is-not-available?forum=sharepointcustomization

Answer (score 0):

Enable workflows in the site collection features and site features.
U can find these settings under site settings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like Your workflow Manager is not properly configured.

First, we have to check if Workflow Proxy is properly connected.
Go to the Central admin > Application Management > Manager service Application
On this page you will see the Workflow Service Application proxy, click on it and on next page it should say connected.

If you are not getting above then it is not even registered.

Here are the guideline for the successful installation of the Workflow Manager 1.0. It is in the PDF.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2016-Workflow-acd5ba2a